# how to stored procedures with bigquery?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I want to replace text and column name by stored procedures and it didn't change the value.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dataset.test_pivot(name STRING)
 BEGIN
 
 SELECT 'name',* FROM
 (
    SELECT 
   name
   FROM `dataset.mytable`
 )
 PIVOT
 (
    count(*) AS N
    FOR name in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10')
 );
 END
 
 
 CALL dataset.test_pivot(inte_acedemic);
```

The result is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6PKm.png

I want replace `name` with `inte_acedemic`.  Many thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to change, if you try from the select you just need to add the alias: 'name' as 'inte_acedemic' .

Comment: also, you might want to provide sample data that you work with so we see context of your case